# Dynamically chained forms with AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I have two models:

```
class ModelA:
    field = models.ForeignKey(ModelB)

class ModelB:
    group = models.CharField(choices=GROUPS)
    subgroup = models.CharField(choices=SUBGROUPS)
```

I have a `CreateView` for `ModelA` which i'm trying to dynamically filter with AJAX:

```
class ModelACreateView(CreateView):

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['groups'] = GROUPS                           // Populate fields in template
        context['subgroups'] = SUBGROUPS
        return context

    def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(ModelACreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update(request=self.request)                  // Pass request to a form
        return kwargs
```

Then in forms:

```
class ModelACreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, request=None, **kwargs):
        super(ModelACreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        group = request.GET.get('group')         // Get data from AJAX request
        subgroup = request.GET.get('subgroup')
        qs = ModelB.objects.filter(group=group, subgroup=subgroup)
        self.fields['field'].queryset = qs
```

Here's the script:

```
    $("#group_select, #subgroup_select").change(function () {
      var endpoint = "{% url 'new_model' %}";             // URL to CreateView
      var group = $("#group_select").val();
      var subgroup = $("#subgroup_select").val();

      $.ajax({
        url: endpoint,
        data: {
          'group': group,
          'subgroup': subgroup,
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $("#id_field").load(" #id_field");
        }
      });

    });
```

But i'm having a problem reloading the `field`: it renders empty. When i check logs, i see that the form gets the `group`, loads `qs`, but then i see another `GET request`, which doesn't have `group` from AJAX and i get rendered empty form field. How do i rewrite the AJAX correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the same `change` event listener for two different selects.  Which means the query will only include both values the second time it is called. There are a few different options that you can use to solve this.

The simplest way that doesn't require a lot of changes is simply detecting if both `group` and `subgroup` have values before processing of the ajax.

```
$("#group_select, #subgroup_select").change(function () {
  var endpoint = "{% url 'new_model' %}";             // URL to CreateView
  var group = $("#group_select").val();
  var subgroup = $("#subgroup_select").val();

if(group != "" && subgroup != ""){

  $.ajax({
    url: endpoint,
    data: {
      'group': group,
      'subgroup': subgroup,
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $("#id_field").load(" #id_field");
    }
  });
}
});
```

Comment: The same issue, I think it's ```$("#id_field").load(" #id_field");``` . It doesn't reload with current data, but makes another request to ```ModelACreateForm``` missing data from AJAX request

Comment: I didn't even catch that typo, what data is being returned in the ajax? And what is expected for it to do, that part wasn't exactly clear.

Comment: What typo? The idea is that ```self.fields['field'].queryset``` re-queries every time the group or subgroup fields are changed.